# How to not load the table when edit in searchbar

Tags: ios, searchbar

I have a search bar on top of a table view,I don't want to reload the table when I begin to edit searchbar text. I already implemented following methods and set the return value to NO：

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString;
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption;
```

I want black mask to persist and I don't want table to dynamically reload until I tap on SearchButton.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this delegate method:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSString *textBeingSearched = searchBar.text;
    //do something with textBeingSearched
}
```

Also make sure that there's nothing in this method:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

}
```

Not bad for a first question. If this answer is satisfactory, please remember to click the checkmark in order to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you,but table still load and black mask hide when I first edit